# Some services are not able to be constructed in .net core api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on creating a .net core API with MongoDB.

Following is my MongoDBSettings.cs

```
public class MongoDBSettings : IMongoDBSettings
    {
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
        public string CollectionName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        
    }

    public interface IMongoDBSettings
    {
        string DatabaseName { get; set; }
        string CollectionName { get; set; }
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Following is appsettings.json file

```
{
  "MongoDBSettings": {
    "CollectionName": Collname,
    "ConnectionString": connStr,
    "DatabaseName": Dbname
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Following is my Service class

```
public class InvoiceService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Invoice> _invoice;
        public InvoiceService(IMongoDBSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

            _invoice = database.GetCollection<Invoice>(settings.CollectionName);
        }

        public List<Invoice> Get() =>
            _invoice.Find(invoice => true).ToList();
    }
```

Following is my Controller Class

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InvoiceController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly InvoiceService _invoiceService;

        public InvoiceController(InvoiceService invoiceService)
        {
            _invoiceService = invoiceService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<Invoice>> Get() =>
            _invoiceService.Get();

    }
```

And following is my startup.ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.Configure<MongoDBSettings>(
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MongoDBSettings)));

            services.AddSingleton<MongoDBSettings>(sp =>
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDBSettings>>().Value);
            services.AddSingleton<InvoiceService>();

            services.AddControllers();

        }
```

When I run it I get the following error:

> System.AggregateException: 'Error while validating the service
> descriptor 'ServiceType: IDP_API.Services.InvoiceService Lifetime:
> Singleton ImplementationType: IDP_API.Services.InvoiceService'
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'IDP_API.Models.IMongoDBSettings' while attempting to activate
> 'IDP_API.Services.InvoiceService'.

I tried changing

```
 services.AddSingleton<InvoiceService>();
```

to

```
services.AddTransient<InvoiceService>();
```

and

```
services.AddScoped<InvoiceService>();
```

But neither of them work.

Can someone please help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMongoDBSettings` was not registered with the service collection so when you try to inject `IMongoDBSettings` into `InvoiceService`

```
public InvoiceService(IMongoDBSettings settings)
```

you get that error

Consider doing the following instead

```
services.AddSingleton<IMongoDBSettings>(sp =>
    sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDBSettings>>().Value);
```

Note the interface is used when registering settings instead of the implementation.

It is also noted that the section name `"MongoDBSettings"` was not seen in the shown `appsettings.json` so there may be further issues with the current system

Comment: Thank you so much that worked like a charm. And Yes I've added MongoDBSettings in appsettings.json